# Вижу не все ветки в git'е

Tags: git

В оббщем, в проекте есть submodule.

Я захожу к нему в папку, ввожу git branch -r и вижу:

> origin/HEAD -> origin/master
> origin/master

Хотя в репозитории веток много.
Пробовал git fetch origin, но нефига...
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: насколько мне известно, git fetch используется для запушивания коммитов в выбранную ветку

Comment: а если `git branch -a` ?

Comment: Я вот такое решение нашел https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623862/fetch-in-git-doesnt-get-all-branches